# How to deselect a dropdown list click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created the following chart:

[image]

Using the following code:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
        </head>
        <div class="x_content" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:black;width:250px;height:170px;background:#ffffff;border:1px solid black;">
            <div id="pieChart" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Forecast Customer Activity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <head>
                    <style>
                        .dropbtn {
                            background-color: #ffffff;
                            color: black;
                            padding: 4px;
                            font-size: 10px;
                            border: box;
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }

                        .dropdown {
                            position: relative;
                            display: inline-block;
                        }

                        .dropdown-content {
                            display: none;
                            position: absolute;
                            background-color: #f9f9f9;
                            min-width: 60px;
                            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                        }

                        .dropdown-content a {
                            color: black;
                            padding: 4px 4px;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            display: block;
                        }


                        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

                        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                            display: block;
                        }

                        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                            background-color: #3e8e41;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                </body>

                <body>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Dropdown</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="Voice">Voice</a>
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="Data">Data</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Dropdown</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="s4">0-4</a>
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="s408">4-8</a>
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="s812">8-12</a>
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="s1216">12-16</a>
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="s1620">16-20</a>
                            <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="s2024">20-24</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">


                var Chart = dc.pieChart("#pieChart");
                d3.csv("data/Forecast_Customer_Activity.csv", function (error, experiments) {

                    var ndx = crossfilter(experiments),
                            Age_GrpDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                                return d.Age_Grp;
                            }),
                            Age_GrpGroup = Age_GrpDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
                        return d.usage;
                    });
                    usage_cat = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                        return d.Usage_category;
                    }),
                            timewindow = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                                return d.Timewindow;
                            }),
                            Chart
                            .width(270)
                            .height(120)

                            .slicesCap(5)

                            .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#458dd1", "#cc7e30", "#a39d97", "#FFDA33", "#0f63bc", "#E51F30"]))
                            .dimension(Age_GrpDimension)
                            .group(Age_GrpGroup)

                            .legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(25).itemHeight(10).gap(2))


                            .on('pretransition', function (chart) {
                                chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function (d) {
                                    return  Math.round(dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2 * Math.PI) * 100) * 10) / 10 + '%';
                                })
                            })

                    Chart.render();
                });

                d3.select('#Voice').on('click', function () {
                    usage_cat.filter("Voice");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });

                d3.select('#Data').on('click', function () {
                    usage_cat.filter("Data");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });

                d3.select('#s4').on('click', function () {
                    timewindow.filter("00-04");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });
                d3.select('#s408').on('click', function () {
                    timewindow.filter("04-08");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });
                d3.select('#s812').on('click', function () {
                    timewindow.filter("08-12");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });
                d3.select('#s1216').on('click', function () {
                    timewindow.filter("12-16");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });
                d3.select('#s1620').on('click', function () {
                    timewindow.filter("16-20");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });
                d3.select('#s2024').on('click', function () {
                    timewindow.filter("20-24");
                    dc.redrawAll();
                });

            </script>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is working fine. Even the `drop down` selections.

When I click on a value under `drop down` it selects the corresponding value in the `pie chart`. Now, when I click the same `drop down` value again it should deselect the value in the pie chart.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle of this?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have the seperate `html`,`css` and `javascript` codes. So, I cant provide `jsFiddle`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Why don't you work a bit smarter with the click handlers?

instead of

```
 d3.select('#s812').on('click', function () {
      timewindow.filter("08-12");
      dc.redrawAll();
});
```

for each option, you can put as an attribute of the `btn-secondery` the filter value like this:

```
 <div class="dropdown-content usage_cat">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" filter='00-04' type="button"  id="s4">0-4</a>
      <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" filter='04-08' type="button"  id="s408">4-8</a>
      <a href="#"class="btn btn-secondary" filter='08-12' type="button"  id="s812">8-12</a>
      <!--etc....--->
  </div>
```

and then you can use one function like this:

```
$('.usage_cat').on('click','.btn-secondary',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active'){ // this is the active filter - cancel it
         //clear filters - not sure how :-)
         dc.redrawAll();
         $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
       $('.active').removeClass('active'); //clear all the other 'active'
       $(this).addClass('active') // give this 'active' class
       var filter = $(this).attr('filter'); // get the 'filter' attribute from node
       usage_cat.filter(filter);
       dc.redrawAll();
    }
})
```

this is only valid for the `usage_cat` filtering, but I hope this gets you started and you can finish the rest yourself

Comment: also have a look at the .toggle() function of jQuery

Comment: Where do you think it can be used here? nothing gets hidden.. maybe you meant toggleClass ?

Comment: .toggle() lets you also run two different functions on alternate clicks. see http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ Edit: ah, unfortunately it's deprecated

Comment: yeah, and there is no alternative for it :/ maybe you can build an onclickevent which checks for the selected attribute of the list element and then perform two different tasks

Comment: I'm sure we all have our little techniques for this (I sometimes use DOM node properties) but in this case this is simplest don't you think?

Comment: yeah I think, it's basically the same :)

Answer (score 0):

What about putting a variable to toggle the value

Create a variable called

> var currentFilter = ""

and each click function will use this variable.
The code should be changed from this:

```
d3.select('#Voice').on('click', function(){
usage_cat.filter("Voice");
dc.redrawAll();
});
```

something like this:

```
...
d3.select('#Voice').on('click', function(){
if(currentFilter !== "Voice")
    currentFilter = "Voice"
else{
    currentFilter = ""
}
usage_cat.filter(currentFilter);
dc.redrawAll();
});
...
```

Of course, you can do much more refactoring to remove duplication overall.

P.S. Your "Run Code Snippet" doesn't work. I don't know is this only for me or not.